# AngularJS : add Active effect and hover effect on li

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello I am facing problem to make Li as Active tab, I already add hover effect but How to add Active tab?. I user Angular's ng-show and ng-hide to change icon in li. Here is my code

```
<li ng-mouseenter="show = true" ng-mouseleave="show = false" id="home">
        <img src="images/home.png" ng-hide="show" class="whiteClass" />
        <img src="images/home_h.png" ng-show="show" class="blackClass"/>
    </li>
```

How can i make it as active tab using ng-click??
Thanks in advance

**Update :**

```
<li  ng-mouseenter="liMouaeEnter()" ng-mouseleave="liMouseLeave()" id="issuesLi"  ng-click="navbarclick($event , issueTab)">
        <img src="images/issues.png" ng-class="{'active': !isActive, 'inactive': isActive}"/>
        <img src="images/issues_h.png" ng-class="{'active': isActive, 'inactive': !isActive}"/>

    </li>
```

Here jS file on controller

```
  var navClickBool = false;
  $scope.liMouaeEnter = function(){
    $scope.isActive = false;
    this.isActive = true;
    navClickBool = false
   }

 $scope.navbarclick = function(event , template){
   $scope.isActive = false;  
   this.isActive = true;
   navClickBool = true

 }

 $scope.liMouseLeave = function(){
   if(navClickBool){
      return
   }
   this.isActive = false;
  }
```

Comment: Exactly the same. Toggle (`true`/`false`) a `clicked` variable on `ng-click` then use it in an `ng-class` to add the `active` class.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv : can you explain me bit more??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to toggle a class on an element, not only show/hide it, you can use [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) instead of `ng-hide`/`ng-show`. `ng-class` automatically adds/removes a class based on the truth value of a `$scope` variable. You can toggle that truth value on `ng-click` (that automatically binds the `onClick` event to the DOM node, just like `on-mouseenter` binds `onMouseenter`).

```
<div ng-init="isActive = false">    
    <div ng-click="isActive = !isActive " ng-class="{'active': isActive}">
       <em>Foo</em>
    </div>
</div>
```

You now only have to write the `.active { }` CSS rule.

Also, you can add multiple rules on `ng-class`

`ng-class="{'active': isActive, 'inactive': !isActive}"`

and this will work as expected (switching between the two classes).

Note that I'm using `ng-init` to initialize my Boolean to `false`. You can also initialize it directly in the controller (`$scope.isActive = false;`).

Comment: I try this but not working both at same time, if hover works than Active not working and Active works than hover not working...

Comment: Why would you set `isActive` on `mouseEnter`?

Comment: to add hover effect on it

Comment: Then use `isHovered`, not `isActive`. Don't mix up two different functionalities in the same flag variable.