# Angular.js set tab active and another tabs inactive

Tags: angularjs

In jQuery, sometimes we need to toggle a group of elements to inactive and the clicked element to active. for example:

Sample Markup:

```
<ul>
    <li class="foo-item active">item 1</li>
    <li class="foo-item">item 1</li>
    <li class="foo-item">item 1</li>
    <li class="foo-item">item 1</li>
</ul>
```

Sample Code:

```
$(".foo-item").click(function(){
    $(".foo-item").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

code above will take out the "active" class from all ".foo-item" and then put "active" just on clicked item. This is useful for many kind of ui elements as tabs for example.

**How to do it using Angular.js?**

we have ng-class on the clicked item, but how can I take out the active from another non clicked elements?

Comment: This question are responded, by many ways and cases. In stackoverflow, you could [search and check the list](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=angularjs+active+li), if there is something more specific for your case.

Heres two examples:
- [answer 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24547888/angularjs-add-active-effect-and-hover-effect-on-li)
- [answer 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25291635/angularjs-active-state-not-applying-on-clicked-button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have one array `items` in your controller, that would have various `property` in each element of it.

**Markup**

```
<ul>
    <li class="foo-item" ng-class="{active: item.id == $parent.selected }" 
      ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="$parent.selected = item.id">{{item.text}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.items = [
     {id: 1, text: 'Item 1'},
     {id: 2, text: 'Item 2'},
     {id: 3, text: 'Item 3'},
     {id: 4, text: 'Item 4'}
];
```